# Sharepoint 2010 Explorer View

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, webdav

So I'm having some really weird problems with SharePoint 2010 and viewing document libraries in Windows Explorer with WebDAV.

I've got two separate farms setup, one for dev/testing and the other for production. On my dev/testing farm, explorer view works fine. Click the button and it opens up nicely. I can also map drive letters to the document library.

However, it doesn't work with my production farm. Trying to open explorer view from an XP client, I get an error message saying "\\ is not accessible. blah blah. Logon Failure: The target account name is incorrect"
As far as I can tell, they are configured identically. The only major difference is the two servers are hosted in different data centers.

Anyone have any hints as to how I can go about troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that's interested:
The problem turned out to be not having a root site collection on my web application. I had to break out Wireshark and MS Network monitor to do some packet sniffing to get to the bottom of it, but the summary of it all is that while WebDAV would make the initial queries to the site collection path, it would eventually make an OPTIONS request to the server for the root, and things would get wonky from that point forward. Once I added an empty site collection at the root, the server would properly respond to the OPTIONS request, and everything would continue on from there.